# C++ double free or corruption(out)

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I came across this error when I was using iterators with vector STL.

Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_vec(std::vector<int> vec)
{
    auto itr = vec.begin();
    while (itr != vec.end())
        std::cout << *itr++ << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vals = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    print_vec(vals);
    auto it = vals.begin();
    vals.insert(it, 100);
    print_vec(vals);
    it += 4;
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
    vals.insert(it, 200);
    print_vec(vals);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
100 1 2 3 4 5 6 
5
0 100 1 2 3 4 5 6 
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I do not understand why this is happening: is it an issue with the iterator after the vector is modified? I think that my intuition regarding iterators is flawed.

Comment: `std::vector<int>::iterator itr=vec.begin();` --> `auto itr = vector.begin();` , please. For readability.

Comment: The code is gambling with iterator invalidation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `std::vector` is resized, the iterator becomes invalid because it refers to the vector *before* resizing which may include *moving* the vector to a different memory location in order to maintain a contiguity. In that case `it` will not be automatically updated to refer to the new location.

The result *in this case* (because it is *undefined* behaviour) is that the value `200` was not inserted in the vector, but it was written to some other heap memory that the vector previously occupied that has since been deallocated - i.e. you corrupted the heap.  The vector is destroyed on exit from main, and at that time the system heap management fails and the error is reported (after the fact).

Reassigning the iterator following the insertion resolves the issue:

```
it = vals.insert(it,100);
...
```

The output of the single item reports 5 rather then 4 as you might expect because it is simply reading the old vector memory not yet reused and overwritten with something else.

You can observe the error by comparing:

```
vals.insert(it,100);
std::cout<<std::distance(it,vals.begin())<<'\n' ;
```

with

```
it = vals.insert(it,100);
std::cout<<std::distance(it,vals.begin())<<'\n' ;
```

Your results are likely to differ but at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ when I performed the test, the distance between the iterator position and the vector start in the first case was 16 - demonstrating that the iterator no longer refers to an element in the current vector state.  In the second case the distance is zero - the iterator refers to the start of the new vector state.

If the capacity of `vals` were extended *before* taking the iterator by for example:

```
vals.reserve(10);
```

Then the insertion of a single element would not cause a mem-move, and the failure would not have occurred - that does not make it a good idea not to update the iterator though - it is merely to indicate what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

> ...is it an issue with the iterator after the vector is modified?

Yes!

From the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) on `std::vector.insert()` (bolding mine):

> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old
>   capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), **all
>   iterators and references are invalidated**. Otherwise, only the
>   iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The
>   past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Comment: it = vals.insert(it,100); // fixes it